# My favourite moment is/was...?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

> My favourite moment in Hanoi **was** riding in a cyclo.
>   My favourite moment in Hanoi **is** riding in a cyclo.

Which one is correct? The original text used 'was'. However, I am more for 'is' because 'riding a cyclo' was and still is my favourite moment. The feeling of me liking it does not change with time, hence the present tense is more suitable here. Could anyone tell me why I am wrong? Thank s a lot : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine.  Neither is "better".

One of the quirks of English is that we sometimes adjust our word choice and tense to match the *perspective* we want to convey.

In this case, using the past tense suggest you enjoy the memory of an event that *happened in the past*.  Meanwhile, using the present tense suggests you are *presently still enjoying* that memory.

> My first clear memory **was** of my father taking me to play at the beach.
>
> My first clear memory **is** of my father taking me to play at the beach.

Both of these are acceptable, but each has slightly different *nuance*.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that we can express *both* tenses in the same sentence:  "My favorite moment in Hanoi **is** when I **was** riding in a cyclo."  The past-tense occurrence remains the present-tense favorite.